# Are travel adapters safe to use permanently?

Tags: adapter, cellphone

I got a phone from Malaysia and it comes with a UK charger(I think? see pictures).

[image]
[image]

I live in EU and would need to use an adapter permanently to charge it using the fast charger it came with.

Is it completely safe? (no fire risk or damage to the phone or the house)

Answer (score 1):

If the adapter is properly specified and built, there is no reason for it to be dangerous, especially given the low power it will need to deal with.

Given the low price of a generic phone charger, it is probably a good idea to just buy one that fits a European socket.

Answer (score 1):

Its harder to say these days, as some can be built rather poorly, while others are just fine, There is nothing inherently wrong with using the adapter, just comes down to how safe the actual adapter is,

If it can be opened easily, you would want to see that each bit of copper was spaced at least 5mm apart from each other, ideally with a little plastic wall in between them for creepage distance. this would be a good way to know how unlikely an electric arc is to form, which would be the primary way you would ever risk it catching fire,

Malasia uses 240V, UK uses 230V, so the adapter would not increase the risk for the phone,

Comment: Actually the UK is 240V as well - the EU rules were given a lax interpretation so that the UK did not have to change its voltage. Also the UK and Malaysia plugs are the same so the UK charger is the correct one to use.